# How to properly terminate dish washer / garbage disposal?

Tags: dishwasher, garbage-disposal

**Introduction**

I am renovating a house and had an electrician come in to update power, run new outlets, etc. I will be installing a garbage disposal that uses a switch (switch already installed) and a dishwasher.  The electrician left an open junction box with wire nuts on the connections for the garbage disposal and a set of 3 wires coming out of the wall for the dishwasher. Each are on their own circuit now.

**How to properly connect?**

I am capable of whatever method is needed but I want to know two things:

1. For the garbage disposal I can connect the wires via wire nut to the garbage disposal wires without a problem but do I leave the junction box open without a cover? That doesn't seem right.. How to I close it up properly?
2. For the dishwasher a similar question, I can connect the wires to the dishwasher via wire nuts too but how do I enclose the connection? Should I install a plug to the end or some other way?

Comment: Personally, I like to add a receptical and put plugs on the end of the wires going to the appliances, but I'm not sure if that's necessarily code.

Comment: @Ben That was one of my thoughts definitely as then it would just be standard outlets with a plug to them

Comment: I'm kind of curious why the electrician wouldn't have done that though.

Comment: Wouldn't hardwiring the dishwasher would require you to have a switch there to shut off the power to service it? Ovens use receptacles and plugs and aren't hardwired, so I wouldn't think it would be any different for dishwashers. I don't know those codes though.

Answer (score 1):

I recently remodeled my kitchen, and the original wiring was just two romex's coming out of the wall and hardwired to the dishwasher and disposal respectively.   There are wiring enclosures on each appliance.  Evidently that was acceptable in times past.

I'm sure our more knowledgeable contributors will come by and cite the current code.

I decided to go with installing a wall box for each circuit, and installing a single 20A receptacle for each (assuming they are 20A 12g circuits).  This allows you to simply and definitively disconnect either when doing any servicing.  It's simple, safe, and straight forward.

You can get an appliance plug that wires into the disposal at the store.  My Bosch diswasher came with a power cord that terminated in a supplied plastic surface mount box.  I put that under the sink and connected an appliance rated cord and plug to it.

Comment: Ha you make me feel silly. I am actually quite certain now that both the disposal and dishwasher can terminate within themselves (a box mounted on each). I will have to check tonight!